# Is there a clean HTML way to relate a key press to a dropdown item

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on an application in which I want to allow for quick data entry.  So I want to make a date field selected by int month value (ie 7 = July).  I think I only have 2 options.

1. Prepend the number to the Month (1 -- Jan, 2 -- Feb, ... etc) but this is Ugly
2. Use JS or jQuery to intercept key presses and select the appropriate month (doable, but messy)

Is there a way to have a hidden locater for a drop down?

-- Edit for Clarity --

I am trying to allow users to input the date through the keyboard more easily so instead of using a calendar picker (which I have) they could type .... 1 tab 1 tab 2010, which would result in the date Jan 1st, 2010

Comment: If you do keypresses, you will have to come up with a way to select Nov and Dec as they are two digit numbers. This, like you said, gets messy. I would suggest using an auto-complete, as two letters of the month should be enough to select it.

Comment: What is it your asking/trying to solve? This could be written better

Comment: Kudos to sworoc for being able to make a reply!

Comment: You know a browser switch might clear this ugly situation up - several browsers will auto-complete for you on a drop-down list.  Type `7` on a selectbox with focus, and -behold- it will set to 7, `tab` to the next box and carry on.  You also spare yourself cross compatibility & upgrade issues (by leaving the browser to deal with), dealing with delays in typing (user changed mind? user slow?), handling backtracking sequences (esc, backspace,arrows, del, etc)

Comment: Question is: do you need it to be a select? A normal input field could hold 'Jan','jan','januar','1','01', and you can interpret it at your leisure?

Comment: @sworoc - October feels left out :(

Comment: Wrikken, I would like to control the input, and only certain users have requested this feature. To change the interface that drastically is not something I believe will be a viable option for my situation.

Comment: I took a quick glance at some travel sites, and it seems like most of them pre-populate a single text box with a date in numeric format (1/1/2011) and this prompts their users to alter the date in a format they expect.  What is your motivation for having multiple selects instead of this more common implementation? that being said, in most browsers you can select a text box then just start typing and it will go to the nearest match.  I find that especially useful with long lists of dates.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to get it working:

```
$(function()
{
    $.each($("select.month"), function() { new MonthSelector(this); });
});

var MonthSelector = function(that)
{
    var self = this;
    $(that).bind("keypress", function(event) { self.onKeyPress(event); } );
    this.two = false;
    this.select = that;
};

MonthSelector.prototype.onKeyPress = function(event)
{
    if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) return;
    var digit = event.which - 48;

    if (this.two && digit <= 2)
    {
        digit += 10;
        this.two = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.two = (digit == 1);
    }

    if (digit != 0) 
        this.select.selectedIndex = digit - 1; 
};
```

It's hard coded to work with 1-12 for simplicity's sake. (The date and year drop downs should automatically work by virtue of the browser's built in functionality.)

This also shouldn't affect the user's ability to (e.g.) type "Dec" for December.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `accesskey` attribute in HTML, which allows specifying to allow access using `[Alt] + Character`. But I don't know, whether this works for `<option>`:

```
<select>
    <option accesskey="1">January</option>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

Comment: From the HTML specs: "The following elements support the accesskey attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, LABEL, and LEGEND, and TEXTAREA." But regardless, this would not work for Oct-Dec nor if there were multiple date boxes on the same page.

Comment: @konforce: [The HTML5 Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute) allows this attribute on other elements, too, that's not the problem. The question is whether browser implement this for dropdowns ;) But yes, you're right, obviously this will fail with multiple month selects on one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript easily. Just check for a selected drop-down box (onfocus) and keypress, if 1 is pressed then select the first element, 2 - second and so on. May also need to add some delay and wait for a second keypress in case of multiple digit numbers.

Alternatively you can try something not standard:

```
<label for="state">State:</label>
<select id="state" name="state">
    <option accesskey="1">.1.</option>
    <option accesskey="2">.2.</option>
    <option accesskey="3">.3.</option>
    <option accesskey="4">.4.</option>
</select>
```

By pressing Alt+Number you will be able to select elements in the drop-down. Just add `accesskey` attribute to the options dynamically (JavaScript) to your focused drop-down box.

Comment: -1 And I really do not appreciate it if my answer get's stolen. I will revert my vote is you roll back your answer to its original form.

Comment: It is not standard because it is not in w3 standard (duh!) and it is not guaranteed to work in different web browsers. Got stolen? How old are you, 10? It is not a race, I am pretty sure all comments were posted around the same time, so I didn't even see your reply when I was typing.

Comment: By the way, the following elements support the accesskey attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, LABEL, and LEGEND, and TEXTAREA.